# Missing image in Facebook sharing by UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, ios-simulator

I've got a weird problem. I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to share a text and a photo. It works with iMessage, Twitter, however with Facebook I can only see the text being shared, the image is missing.. any idea please?

Facebook also works correctly (uploads both photo and text) but only on the simulator, on the device only text is shared on the Facebook.

Maybe I need to fill some facebookID or something in the plist..?

Here's the code:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewControntroller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[shareText, image] applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewControntroller.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    activityViewControntroller.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.shareButton;
    activityViewControntroller.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.shareButton.bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(self.shareButton.bounds), 0, 0);
}
[self presentViewController:activityViewControntroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

-- edit ---

The device environment:

- iPhone SE, iOS 10.1.1,
- Facebook credentials in the Settings app are filled properly
- Facebook app version 74.2 - with the same user logged in as in the Facebook section in the Settings app

The simulator environment:

- iPhone SE simulator, iOS 10.1
- Facebook credentials in the Settings app are filled properly
- obviously no Facebook app

Answer (score 1):

Try resizing the image down before presenting the `UIActivityViewControntroller`.

The image I was trying to use was 6048 x 6048, and testing on a device made the Facebook share dialog close like you reported. Once I resized the image down to 2048 x 2048 it posted up to FB just fine.

Comment: Facebook policy did change. They do not allow to post both the text and the photo at the same time. If you have the Facebook application installed, you'll be unable to share both.

Comment: I was unable to find the "Facebook policy" you referenced in your comment. I was looking here https://developers.facebook.com/policy ... did I look in the wrong place? Or are you referring to 13.5.a? "Don't prefill quotes with content a person didn’t select, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing."

Answer (score -3):

You need to use FaceBook SDK for sharing image because UIActivityViewController dose't support image sharing through Facebook

Comment: Interesting that if I share only the image then it works. Also in the API docs they write the opposite thing than you claim. Provide me any reference upholding your words. All the obvious ones are against you, strictly said eg here: http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/.